VS code extension inside NX workspace - Cannot find module 'vscode'
I'm having trouble creating a new vscode-extension inside an NX workspace. For some reason it doesn't seem to run. The repository with the code has been pushed here. These are the commands I ran to create the workspace:
npx create-nx-workspace
> vscodetest
> Node
> None
> Integrated monorepo
> vscodeextension
> No Dockerfile
> Do it later - CICD
> No remote caching
cd vscodetest
npm i vscode
code .

main.ts
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "mintplayer-vidyano-extension" is now active!');

    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('vscode-extension.helloWorld', () => {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from mintplayer-vidyano-extension!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}

// Run: npx nx build
// F5
// ctrl+P
// > Hello world

.vscode/tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}

.vscode/launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension In Dev Mode",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}/dist/packages/vidyano-extension"
            ],
            "trace": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnFirstSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/packages/vidyano-extension"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}

nx.json
{
  ...,
  "defaultProject": "vscodeextension"
}

Build and run the application:
npx nx build
npx nx serve vscodeextension

And actually you would also need a package.json inside the project
{
  "name": "vscodeextension",
  "displayName": "vscode-extension",
  "description": "Automatically build applications",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.93.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./main.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "vscode-extension.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Now you should be able to hit F5 and this should launch a new VSCode window in debug mode.
However I'm getting the following error

Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'

Call stack
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode' Require stack:

C:\repos\vidyano-extension\dist\packages\vidyano-extension\packages\vidyano-extension\src\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\repos\vidyano-extension\tmp\vidyano-extension\main-with-require-overrides.js:41:36)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.Module._load (C:\repos\vidyano-extension\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node-with-require-overrides.js:18:31)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\repos\vidyano-extension\packages\vidyano-extension\src\main.ts:3:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)

I checked, and the vscode module is actually in the node_modules folder.
How can I fix this?
Edit: Turns out NX Console is a VSCode extension inside an nx workspace too
Edit: I tried from scratch using this walkthrough (repository), but after launching (F5) I still cannot see my custom command. What I do see however, is that the wrong package.json ends up in the /dist/apps/exte folder

